# Maven: download file and run command to build dependency

Tags: java, maven

Recently, a project I need as a dependency for some of my programs has switched to providing patch files instead of actual jars (legal reasons). 
They included a small tool to automatically patch your existing jars with the new update you downloaded.

I could write a small program that automatically downloads and patches the file, all I need is a way to tell maven not to download the file but to run a command and then use the file from my local repo.

Is there a way to do this (maybe using a custom plugin)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I manually install a jar to my local Maven repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871812/how-do-i-manually-install-a-jar-to-my-local-maven-repository)

Comment: That one doesn't answer my question. I need to run this when the dependency is being downloaded or else my IDE will return errors saying that it can't find the dependency

Comment: Does your organization maintain a local maven repository? If so, can you put these delta'd .jar files there?

Comment: You should take a look at the [maven-patch-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-patch-plugin/) it might solve your problem.

Comment: The patcher plugin might work. I'll try it when I get home. Does it patch .bps files?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small ant task run the tool and call this task from your maven build using [maven-antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin.

You could also write your own maven plugin but for such a simle task I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your IDE does not find the dependency is that it is not published anymore (not the version you seek apparently).

Building the artifact and installing it locally as @Joe suggested is an elegant solution to solve your issue from my perspective. 
The advantage is twofold:

1. Your IDE can seamlessly find the missing artifact
2. You can keep multiple version of that dependency (one for every new patch) and thus reproduce previous (working) build in case a new patch breaks something.

if you have a local repository, it is even better as this would maven the dependency available to all your team.

Of course you would still need a tool to download new patch, apply them and deploy the produced artifact to the repository automatically. But doing this as a separate task give you more flexibility concerning the tools you could use.

Comment: I'm using this right now, I was just wondering if there's a way to do this only when maven needs a dependecy and only for the version it needs. These are nightly build so they would use up my disk space very quickly.