# How to put jars in maven repository to allow pom.xml recognise them from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

my project needs some jars that i get from a shared file in my company,
I put those jars into the repository and added the dependencies to my pom.XML
but have an error "Missing artifact .."

When i check the repository, all the jars are inside files except the ones i've added manually

i need to know now what is the best way to add jars into the repository 
Here is a picture of the missed artifacts[image: Pom.xml missed artifacts]

Comment: check [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Comment: @mustabelMo can you please tell me where do i have to excecute the commands shown in this site ? I'm working with Windows 10

Comment: First you have to install maven, add its bin folder to your path variables, and then point your command line console onto the folder that contains the jar(s) you wanted to install

Comment: Is the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871812/how-do-i-manually-install-a-jar-to-my-local-maven-repository) question you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the jars into a repository like Nexus or Artifactory. This can be done through Maven (`mvn deploy:deploy-file`) or the web interface of the repository.
2. Add the repository to your `settings.xml`.
3. Reference them in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: does it work if i put them into my actual repository "D:\UserFolder\userx\.m2\repository" and i can't found the setting.xml file in my project !

Comment: Do you want them in you _local_ repository or in a company repository? The settings.xml should be in your .m2 directory. If it is not present, you have the standard settings, i.e. you contact MavenCentral.